# Python Column / Fieldnames combine

Tags: python, python-3.x, prettytable

I want to create a table with 2 headings but 5 entries / columns and get this problem:

```
Exception("Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) %d!=%d (expected)" %(len(row),len(self._field_names)))
Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 5!=2 (expected)
```

How can I combine column 1 and column 2 in the title

Input:

```
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| Field 1  | Field 2  | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| Adelaide | Brisbane |  Darwin |  Martin | Summary |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Test1   |  Test2   |  Test3  |  Test4  |  Result |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+

from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
x.hrules = 1
x.vrules = 1
x.header = True
x.add_row(["Adelaide","Brisbane","Darwin","Martin","Summary"])
x.add_row(["Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Result"])
print(x)
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|                    Names                | End     |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| Adelaide | Brisbane |  Darwin |  Martin | Summary |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Test1   |  Test2   |  Test3  |  Test4  |  Result |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: If you're open to using pandas, have a look at the .MultiIndex. Should help you out.

Comment: I have no experience with pandas :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Pandas here is a snippet that should work. Not sure how your headers and data would be read in so I am confident that you could make this more flexible, but just showing you how Pandas and MultiIndex can be used.
Pandas is really good when working with data and gives you loads of built in features so if this is something you will do regularly I would suggest having a look at a demo and seeing what you think.

```
    import pandas as pd
    header_row_1 = ["Names", "Names", "Names", "Names", "End"] 
    header_row_2 = ["Adelaide","Brisbane","Darwin","Martin","Summary"]  
    data = ["Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4", "Result"]
    tuples = list(zip(header_row_1, header_row_2)) 
    cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
    df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns = cols)
```